# The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api2, android-ion

I'm trying to send an HTTP post request from Android using Ion framework to ASP.NET WebAPI v2. Here is what I've done so far.

In ASP.NET WebAPI:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult SubmitPosition([FromBody] string foo, string bar)
{
   return Json(new { serversay = "Im foo-bar" });
}
```

In Android:

```
JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
json.addProperty("foo", "this is foo");
json.addProperty("bar", "Its bar");

Ion.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load("http://182.160.99.115:1012/api/PositionSubmit/SubmitPosition")
                .setJsonObjectBody(json)
                .asJsonObject()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
                        String ServerSaid =  result.get("serversay").getAsString();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ServerSaid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
```

I'm getting `The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'`.
Any help?

Comment: Can we get more context on the WebAPI end?  Can you add a simplified version of the Controller to this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using attribute routing? The method should not be in the Url too:

Instead of

"http://182.160.99.115:1012/api/PositionSubmit/SubmitPosition"

can your try:

"http://182.160.99.115:1012/api/PositionSubmit"

Comment: i was placing wrong URL while calling API. Issue fixed